# Alternative design for calling specific utility method based on which category is implemented in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I am using category to add functionality to my class. However I would like to share a common method in main class which, if invoked, would call the specific category method.

I explain better, supposing I have two category.

```
@interface MyClass(CategoryA) 

-(void)specificCategoryA;

@end


@interface MyClass(CategoryB) 

-(void)specificCategoryB;

@end
```

then, in my main class I would like to have:

```
@implementation MyClass

    -(void)utilityMethod {

      // choose one of the two...
      // -(void)specificCategoryB;
      // -(void)specificCategoryA;

    }

@end
```

I know the above cannot be done, in a sense that categories cannot be introspected, so I am looking for an alternative way. For the app I am working on, it would be fine to solve this at compile time, but I am open to any suggestion.
I also tried to override a common method name, but I obviously get the warning

> Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by
>   its primary class

which doesn't mean things will not work, but I do not want to use category as inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a compile-time decision you can use a preprocessor

```
#if some-constant-condition
  [mc specificCategoryA];
#else
  [mc specificCategoryB];
#endif
```

Comment: Yes, what to write in some-constant-condition ? Can I, for example, identify the UIViewController subclass ?

Comment: @Leonardo No, there is no reflection (or any Objective-C feature for that matter) during preprocessor stage. As Sulthan already said it is better to describe in more detail what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your problem is why can't you use an if statement two choose which method is called.

Also what you are trying to do looks like you could use an abstract base class that implements the common utilityMethod code and then have two subclasses that override utilityMethod like

```
-(void)utilityMethod
{
    [super utilityMethod];
    // subclass specific code.
}
```

then have your subclasses implement the specificCategoryA logic in one subclass specificCategoryB logic on another subclass.

You hide the subclasses from uses of your MyClass, by implementing it as a Cluster class. You init method for MyClass release the object created and then creates a SubClasses depending on whatever you conditions are, or you can create a Class method that creates an initialise a subclass of MyClass for you. The user doesn't need to know which subclass it is, its just some kind of MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(specificCategoryA)]) {
   [object specificCategoryA];
}
else if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(specificCategoryB)]) {
   [object specificCategoryB];
}
```

However, it seems to me there is a problem with your design - wouldn't preprocessor be better?

Comment: Yes, as I stated, preprocessor would be fine too. I am just try to find alternative way to the above design. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @Leonardo You can try my solution or describe more what you are trying to do and WHY.